# I am trying to resolve the data in map function

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Below is my code.I am unable resolve the o/p.How to resolve in async and await.I am trying to get data from other collection and pass it to existing filtered collection

```
exports.listStatus = async (root, { _id, start, limit }) => {
  var user = await db.User.find({ _id: _id })    
    let list = user[0].savedUsers
    var blocked = user[0].blockedUsers
    var listAll = list.push(_id)
    let listOfStatus = await db.Status.find({ userId: { $in: list }, reportStatus: { $ne: _id }, _id: { $nin: blocked } });
    let array;
    let leng = listOfStatus.length
    let statusCommentsArray
    var arrayStatus = [];
    listOfStatus.forEach((status, key) => {
      let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var obj = {}
        var statusId = status._id
        var listOfLiked = status.like
        let likeCount = listOfLiked.length
        var sortedList = listOfLiked.sort({ createdDate: -1 })
        obj.likeCount = likeCount

        db.Comment.find({ statusId: statusId }, (err, statusCommentsList) => {
          var statusCommentsCount = statusCommentsList.length
          var sortedList = statusCommentsList.sort({ createdDate: -1 })
          if (statusCommentsCount >= 3) {
            statusCommentsArray = sortedList
          }
          else {    
            statusCommentsArray = sortedList.slice(0, 3)
          }
          obj.statusCommentsCount = statusCommentsCount
          obj.statusCommentsArray = statusCommentsArray
          arrayStatus.push(obj)
          leng--;
          if (leng == 0) {
            resolve(arrayStatus)
          }          
        })    
      })
      promise.then((response) => {
        return Promise.resolve(response)
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the "o/p" that you try to resolve? What have you **tried** to resolve that mystery?

Comment: return Promise.resolve(response) @Nico Haase

Comment: "o/p" = original promise?